# Difference between Boost and Pthread condition variables

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads, mutex, boost-thread

I found some code using boost threads, mutexes and condition variables but I wanna try to rewrite this code with posix threads.

This is the Boost code, I´ve found [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html):

```
void push(Data const& data)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
    the_queue.push(data);
    lock.unlock();
    the_condition_variable.notify_one();
}
```

In my code using pthreads I am not sure if I´m using the condition variables the right way because I am not sure if notify_one() and singalling the variables is the same:

```
void push(T const& data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);
    m_queue.push(data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&m_condition);
}
```

Initializing is done right before like that:

```
pthread_mutex_t m_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t m_condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

At another point they are using `the_condition_variable.wait(lock);` ... this line I would rewrite with pthreads like that: `pthread_cond_wait( &m_condition, &m_mutex);`

Am I on the right track?

Comment: One is a C++ class with a C++ interface, the other a C-style structure with a C-style interface? Most probably the Boost implementation is using the pthread interface for its implementation behind the scenes.

Comment: Hm so I should always unlock the mutex because there is no instance (like in the boost implementation) that would be destroyed when leaving the push function or any other function, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of the Boost threading primitives are based on
`pthread`, so there should be no difference at that level.
Boost wraps them in a C++ class based interface, however, and in
particular, supports RAII implicitly for things like locking the
mutex; if you want to use `pthread` directly, you'll definitely
want to implement your own variant of scoped lock, for example.
As it stands, your implementation of `push` fails to release the
lock if `m_queue.push( data )` throws (and it can throw).

Also, you should signal *before* releasing the lock.  (This is
an error both in your Boost code and in your pthread code.)  And
avoid the code in the site you cite: it is completely broken,
and not at all thread safe.

### EDIT:

After more investigation: I see that the site you quote is
authored by Anthony Williams, who has a *very* high reputation
with regards to threading issues.  At the bottom of the page, he
has a "The Final Code" version which *is* correct, in every
detail.  Although it doesn't seem clear to me, on reading the
page, I think that all of the preceding versions (including the
one you're copying from) are given as "first drafts", and known
to be incorrect in some details.  (I still think that he should
make this clearer.  There are some extremely dangerous practices
in his first example: returning references, for example.)

Comment: Thanks, I read the comments to the article I've cited and they mentioned that is not a good solution. I came up with a new solution: http://pastebin.com/sBZqBtmZ ... is this better?

Comment: No.  It's full of race conditions, and will also fail to unlock the mutex if there is an exception.  A correct solution must 1) use RAII to ensure that the mutex is freed, whatever, 2) lock at the top of each function, and free at the bottom, with the only intervening unlock that implied in the wait, and 3) loop on the wait, testing the condition. And it should use `pthread_cond_t`, and not `sem_t`, since only `pthread_cond_t` will handle the mutex unlocking and locking correctly.

Comment: My first approach looked like that: http://pastebin.com/FSCFWQMD ... but I don't know how to unlock the mutex after empty has been called. Should I also create a Lock-Class like the boost guys?

Comment: First, you don't unlock the mutex after calling `empty`; the mutex _must_ be held when you call `pthread_cond_wait`.  For the rest, you definitely should create a lock class, which locks the mutex in its constructor, and unlocks it in the destructor.  Defining an instance of this should be the first line in all of your functions (and you never need to explicitly unlock the mutex otherwise).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will set this as answer but please let me know if this looks better: http://pastebin.com/VJAKKmPe

Comment: Almost.  There's still no lock guard in `push`, which may be the most important place to put it: if `Data` cannot throw, `push` is the only function where you can get an exception.

Comment: Also note that you will probably want to unlock the mutex *after* calling the notify on the producer thread. [See this page](http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/condvars-signal-with-mutex-locked-or-not/) for details.